# How to create an attached responsive layout using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image]

How to create an attached responsive layout using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <div class="row">

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!--ASIDE-->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">

        </div>
        <!--CONTENT-->
        <div class="col-md-7">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--CONTENT-->
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</div>
```

You will then need to fill the placeholder DIVs to actually see a result but this is a perfectly fine skeleton to start working with. No need to use margins, Bootstrap's column offsets will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however Navigation and Footer are 100% width and with different color.

Comment: @mahirastogi I haven't added any style. It's just a skeleton. If you add content there you will see it. If you don't want the default padding that Bootstrap adds to Navigation and Footer add a CSS class to them with zero padding like this: `padding: 0 !important;`